# How to override data grid cells of a specific column in WPF using some property like Name?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, styling

Basically right now I am using Column Display Index but this is messed up each time I add or remove a column or change their order.

I can't use Column Text because the column text has dynamic text via binding, so I was looking at x:Name property but I am not sure how to use it in the posted sample code. There is no Column.Name for example.

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="S" Width="24" SortMemberPath="Price" x:Name="Price">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Ellipse Width="{Binding Balance.SpotBalanceSize}" Height="{Binding Balance.SpotBalanceSize}" Fill="{Binding Path=Balance.SpotBalanceColor}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="16"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyBackColor}" />
                <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyForeColor}" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with binding to attached property:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="S" Width="24" SortMemberPath="Price" local:AttachedClass.ColName="JoanVenge">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse Width="{Binding Balance.SpotBalanceSize}" Height="{Binding Balance.SpotBalanceSize}" Fill="{Binding Path=Balance.SpotBalanceColor}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.(local:AttachedClass.ColName), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="JoanVenge"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyBackColor}" />
        <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyForeColor}" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
</MultiDataTrigger>

public class AttachedClass
{
    public static string GetColName(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(ColNameProperty);
    }

    public static void SetColName(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ColNameProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColNameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColName", typeof(string), typeof(AttachedClass), new PropertyMetadata(""));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it says: "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error XDG0008 The name "AttachedClass" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ProfitTracker". ProfitTracker 
"

Comment: Is `AttachedClass` in the `ProfitTracker` namespace?

Comment: Yes indeed, nvm rebuilding the project worked. Strange VS reported it as an error before compile.

Comment: Thanks it works great. That will save me having to worry about updating my code each time.

Comment: Actually one last thing if you know how can I access the same property using code? So I can say if ColName == "JoanVenge", do this? I have a hotkey where I am toggling the visibility of some columns.

Comment: `AttachedClass.GetColName(ColumnObject); AttachedClass.SetColName(ColumnObject, "NewColumnName")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, so just loop over the columns and compare the ColName, thanks a lot.